# Why comes infinite while loop in my code and value not come Zero?

Tags: java

I am writing a code of program that reverse my input, the code that I had written is look like this:

```
/*
 * Author: Mohammed Khalid Alnahdi
 *
 * This program is reverse the number.
 * for example 123 to 321
 *
 */

// call utility to take number from the users.
import java.util.Scanner;

class ReverseNumberInput{
        public static void main(String[] args){

        //we call the tool of take number.
                Scanner take = new Scanner(System.in);

                int inputNumberUser, printValue = 0;

                System.out.print("Please enter the number : ");

                inputNumberUser = take.nextInt();

                System.out.print("the reverse number is : ");

                while(inputNumberUser != 0){
                                printValue = inputNumberUser % 10;
                                inputNumberUser = inputNumberUser- printValue;
                                System.out.printf("%d",printValue);
                        }
                }
        }
```

The answer comes for solve this problem by two why

first solution is replace

```
inputNumberUser = inputNumberUser- printValue;
```

by

```
inputNumberUser = inputNumberUser/10;
```

and second one is by

```
                while(inputNumberUser != 0){
                               int digit = inputNumberUser % 10;
                                printValue = printValue * 10 + digit;
                                inputNumberUser = inputNumberUser/10;
                        }
System.out.print(printValue);
```

My Question why my code in the first not give `inputNumberUser` *zero* value while deducting remaining till put the value is zero.

Comment: are you sure that it becomes zero after deducting till the end?

Comment: Do a dry run. Say `inputNumber` is 15, what happens in the while loop, what gets printed as output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the resul of subtraction

`inputNumberUser = inputNumberUser- printValue;` by `10` after each iteration

For example, you have an input `154`

`154 - 4 = 150` is your next `inputNumberUser`

and in the next iteration you have

`150 - 0 = 150` is your next `inputNumberUser`

So your output will be `40000...`

If you divide `inputNumberUser` by `10` after each iteration, you will have

`15 - 5 = 10` is your next `inputNumberUser`

then,

`1 - 1 = 0` is your next `inputNumberUser`